# Ubuntu repositories: difference between samba and samba4

Tags: package-management, samba

As in the title, I found in the Ubuntu repositories two packages, named samba and samba4. Which is the actual difference?

I tried to install samba, but the service didn't seem to be active. Then I installed samba4 and it directly went to the configuration wizard.

Do I have redundant files now?

(moved this question to this section from Unix & Linux)

Answer (score 0):

`apt-cache show samba`

```
This package provides the components necessary to use Samba as a
stand-alone file and print server.  For use in an NT4 domain or Active
Directory realm, you will also need the winbind package.
This package is not required for connecting to existing SMB/CIFS servers
(see smbclient) or for mounting remote filesystems (see cifs-utils).
```

`apt-cache show samba4`

```
These packages contain snapshot versions of Samba 4, the next-generation
version of Samba. These should be considered _experimental_, and should
not be used in production.This package contains the main daemon.
```

Comment: Ok! But if you need "to use Samba as a
stand-alone file and print server" and you want to run the service, you should install both samba and samba4, isn't it? Because the daemon seems to be contained only in samba4, according to that texts.